# In a notebook (.ipynb file) paste double pastes

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

If I copy text from one cell and paste into another cell it double pastes.

If I **cmd+z** to undo it undoes one of the two pastes implying the issue is pasting. In `.ipynb` files, VSC double pastes.

I tried pasting in a `.py` file with no issue. Likewise pasting in the issue reporter has no issue, just in Jupyter Notebook cells.

I manually restarted VSC and the issue went away. After a while (12 minutes of use) the issue randomly came back when pasting between different notebooks.

The issue seems intermittent coming and going seemingly randomly.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101946 a bug which looks like it will be fixed in a recovery build due out soon.

Answer (score 2):

Due to many posts i answer this myself here (for Windows 10)

From **Keyboard Shortcuts** in **VScode**.

search for: `editor.action.clipboardPasteAction`
remove the `CTRL+V` keybinding.

This works in **Windows 10**

VScode version: 1.47.1 (installed in 2020)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this only happens in markdown cells, not code cells. My own solution is to copy the problem cell, paste the new cell below it, and finally delete the original cell.